# Validation Rule on Parent opportunity field by checking child opportunity field

Tags: validation-rule, sales-cloud

We have Parent Opportunity and Child Opportunity Record Types with the same Delete check box field. I am trying to write a validation on the Parent Opportunity - Delete check box field. Unless a user selects 'Delete' check box at the Bid level, they can not mark the Parent Opportunity Delete check box. I am trying to prevent Parent Opportunity mark for Delete unless they mark Child Opportunity as Delete first. This is what I tried but nothing seems working

AND ((AND(RecordType.DeveloperName == "Bid", Delete__c == FALSE)),
Related_Parent_Construction_Bid__r.Delete__c == TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules can't reference child relationships, and validation rules on children don't affect the parent records unless the child records are also updated. Instead, consider making a field on the parent that is updated (e.g. by automation) when the child is updated. You can then validate off of this new field.